# How can I convert a bullet transform to glm matrix without copying data?

Tags: glm-math, bullet

I have a bullet transform and i would like to make it accessible as glm::mat3 type.

However, I am wondering if there is a good to way to do that without copying (like make_mat3x3).

Answer (score 1):

After I skimmed the **GLM**, I found that - without modifying source code - it is impossible.
The copying is required.

Both **Bullet** and **GLM** cache the matrix by **value**, not pointer or reference.

For **Bullet**, see an evidence : http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/btMatrix3x3_8h_source.html
For **GLM**, see an example : https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00132_source.html.

It might be faster if you use `memcpy`, but I am not sure if it is possible.
It depends on how the values are ordered.
(I have limited knowledge about **GLM**)

Even you manage to let two objects reside in the same address,
there will be a horrible issue that hard to be managed. (e.g. double delete)

However, before you try to avoid copying, did you **profile** it?
Copying is not expensive, really.

A few years ago, I wasted a few hours with a similar problem.
In my case, I want to copy **Bullet**'s matrix to **Opengl** buffer.

Nonetheless, after I profiled it, I found that 
in all of my game prototypes, this operation cost less than 1% of the whole logic.

Not worth the effort, really.
*Premature optimization is the root of evil.*